# Why do I lose 10 reputation on 'unupvote' event of a community wiki answer?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, voting, community-wiki

I created [this community wiki answer on ethereum stack exchange beta](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/279/87) some weeks ago. It has 12 upvotes and I do not get reputation for this. This is of course, by design.

However, yesteday I lost 10 reputation because someone voted up and unupvoted again. Here's a screenshot from my reputation tab:

[image: screenshot of the bug]

As you can see, I did not recieve any reputation for the upvote (expected behaviour) but I lost 10 reputation for an immediate unupvote. I'm pretty sure this is a bug.

I am also wondering if this could be exploited to reduce other members reputation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your post was initially not community wiki. According to the [timeline](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/posts/279/timeline), it had 9 upvotes on the day you made it community wiki. [When a post becomes CW, that doesn't affect previous reputation gains (or losses), it only blocks future gains/losses from votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts): you kept the 90 reputation points that you'd gotten from it.

Since you lost reputation to the unupvote, that means the cancelled vote was one of those that you received before the post was CW. So your post now has 8 votes that brought you reputation, and 4 that didn't.

The only case where a vote/unupvote sequence can make you lose reputation is when the upvote didn't earn you the full reputation due to the daily reputation cap, but the unupvote did cost you.

Comment: Okay, so the unupvote was before the upvote? Both have the same timestamp: probably someone misclicked? This is really by-design?

Comment: @5chdn Hmmm. I think what happened is that someone unupvoted by mistake, then immediately re-upvoted. So their pre-CW-conversion vote was removed, and then a new vote was added, post-CW-conversion. (There's no ununupvote.) That makes sense, but it does suck.

Answer (score 3):

The post was made Community Wiki on February 24th, after *most* of the upvotes on it have been made - all of those have given you reputation.

One of those was changed later on - so it stands to reason you would lose that reputation.